# jquery ui autocomplete giving an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PAGE_UP' of undefined"

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use the jquery ui autocomplete, and keep having the following error when you type into the input field that has the autocomplete on it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PAGE_UP' of undefined
```

I have included the following files on my page:

- jquery-1.7.2.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css

Here is the code using the autocomplete:

```
$('input#searchFor').autocomplete({
        source:function(req,add){
            $.getJSON("/index.php/search/autoCompleteHandler?q=?&section="+$('input#searchFor').attr("searchDesc"),req,function(data){
                var suggestions = [];

                $.each(data,function(i,val){
                    suggestions.push(val.name);
                });

                add(suggestions);
            });
        }
    });
```

I have no idea what could be going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `custom.min.js` include? I would bet that if you replace it with jQueryUI in its entirety the error goes away (try http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js instead just to see what happens)

Answer (score 0):

The jQueryUI example documentation for a [remote data source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) shows the remote data source should be done like:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                //the code to execute when an item is clicked on
            }
        });
    });
```

It looks like source only needs to be a url.  You could take a look at the ajax request in Chrome to figure out the $_GET or $_POST variable which is being populated with the search query.

It might not be a bad idea depending on your usage to use the [remote data source with caching](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache) option.